# How does UIScrollView.contentInset work to scroll up the content view?

Tags: uiscrollview, uikit

Situation:
When a Text Field has focus and the keyboard appears, the Text Field is moved up so that it will not be covered by the keyboard.

To implement this, one solution is to add an observer that listens to UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)),
    name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
    object: nil)
```

When a notification comes, we change the contentInset property of the scroll view:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo, let value = info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: value.cgRectValue.height, right: 0)
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, but I don't understand why it works. Changing contentInset above will add padding to the bottom, but the origin of the content view is not changed so the content view should not be moved up.

And if I put the following code in a button tapped event, the view is not moved when I tap the button even though padding is added to the bottom.

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 300, right: 0)
```

Why the first case moves up the view but the second does not?

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell -- setting the `.contentInset` does not automatically change the `.contentOffset`.

If you change your button tap to this:

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 300, right: 0)
scrollView.contentOffset.y = 300.0
```

You will see the content move up.

When the keyboard appears, ***IT*** changes the `.contentOffset` of the scroll view - if it can. Setting the inset bottom *allows* the keyboard to do so.

---

Lot's more info, if you're interested...

The `.contentInset` property of a `UIScrollView` tells UIKit how much it can scroll, relative to its `.contentSize`. Generally, these days, the proper way to set the `.contentSize` is to constraint the scroll view's subviews to the `.contentLayoutGuide` and let auto-layout handle it.

So, let's look at this as a simple example...

We'll use a scroll view, add a label that takes up 80% of the scroll view's height, and then add a text field below the label:

```
class ScrollExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
        // we'll add a label to the scroll view that will take up
        //  80% of the height, so the text field will be near the bottom
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = .cyan
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 36, weight: .regular)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = "This label will take up 80% of the scroll view height.\n\nSo our text field will be near the bottom of the scroll view and will be covered by the keyboard."
        
        // add a text field setup to end editing (dismiss the keyboard) when Enter is tapped
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero, primaryAction: UIAction(title: "") { action in
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        })

        [label, textField, scrollView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        scrollView.addSubview(label)
        scrollView.addSubview(textField)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // inset the scroll view 20-points on all 4 sides
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // constrain label top/leading/trailing to Content Layout Guide
            //  with 8-points "padding"
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            // height 80% of scroll view Frame Layout Guide height
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),

            // width equal to scroll view Frame Layout Guide width
            //  minus 16-points (8 on each side)
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor, constant: -16.0),

            // constrain text field Top to label Bottom plus 20-points
            textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            // constrain text field leading to Content Layout Guide
            //  with 20-points "padding
            textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            // make text field width 40-points less than scroll view width
            textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            // constrain text field bottom to Content Layout Guide
            //  with 20-points "padding
            textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])

        // so we can see the framing
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        textField.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
    }
    
}
```

It will look like this:

[image]

And we can't scroll, because the content height is shorter than the scroll view height.

If we tap into the text field, the keyboard will show and will cover the text field:

[image]

If we add this line at the end of `viewDidLoad()`:

```
// set content inset bottom to 500
scrollView.contentInset = .init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 500.0, right: 0.0)
```

it does not change the scroll view's **current `.contentOffset`**, but we can now scroll up to this point:

[image]

That's not exactly what we want, though. First, we probably don't want the user to be able to scroll like that... and second, when we tap into the text field it will "auto-scroll" to this:

[image]

So, let's remove that line, and instead implement Notification observing.

Add this at the end of `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    // add observer for keyboard will show notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)),
        name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil)
```

and add the handler:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo, let value = info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        // add Bottom content inset, so UIKit can scroll the text field up
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: value.cgRectValue.height, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Everything will look the same on startup (we can't scroll up or down), but when we tap into the text field:

[image]

the keyboard appears, the `.contentInset` bottom is set, and the field auto-scrolls to where we want it.

Note, though... if we stop editing (tap the Return key), we see this:

[image]

because the `.contentInset.bottom` is still set.

So, we also want to take action when the keyboard is dismissed to "reset" the inset.

Add this to `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    // add observer for keyboard will hide notification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)),
        name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil)
```

and a "will hide" handler:

```
@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    scrollView.contentInset = .zero
}
```

Now, when the keyboard is dismissed, the scroll view auto-scrolls back to its original position.

There are a few other things to keep in mind - starting with the scroll view's **actual frame**.

Let's make the scroll view shorter (but still where the text field would be hidden by the keyboard):

[image]

Without any other code changes, tapping into the text field gives us this:

[image]

What we need to do is check where the Top of the keyboard will be, compared to the Bottom of the scroll view, and adjust the inset accordingly.

Let's change the "will show" handler to this:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo, let value = info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let kbTop = value.cgRectValue.minY
        let svBot = scrollView.frame.maxY
        // add 8-points so the text field is not sitting directly on the keyboard
        let h = (svBot - kbTop) + 8.0
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: h, right: 0)
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

Lots of other information out there on how to handle keyboard appearance - worth some searching and reading.

Hopefully, though, this has explained how setting the `.contentInset` works.